# How to use alternate post layout at key points in post loop?

Tags: posts, loop

How can I intervene in my post loop output to show 3 posts in alternate mark-up, and then resume?

I have a post loop that calls my post card template fragment, `card-pair_top.php`, to display like this...

[image]

But, when the post count is high, it looks repetitive. So, at key points, I want to change the layout for visual variance. I want to use my 'feature' `card-overlay.php` theme fragment...

[image]

I want to do this using the same single WP_Query results, `$posts_topic_remainder`, rather than make multiple queries, partly as I want to retain tidy pagination.

Specifically, at points 19, 31 or 43 in the `while` `have_posts` loop, I'd like to break the column `div`s, and even the row `div`, and insert a new nested row mark-up set which itself should display the *next three posts* using `card-overlay.php`.

Then it should restore the mark-up and resume displaying the loop contents using `card-pair_top.php`, until the next break.

Here is the original loop output...

```
    <!-- Posts row -->
    <div class="row px-2">
        <?php
            $i=0;
            // Post Loop
            while ( $posts_topic_remainder->have_posts() ) {
                $posts_topic_remainder->the_post();

                // Impose an offset, skip same number used in features above
                $i++;
                if($i<=$num_features) continue;

                // set_query_var( 'tax_slug_to_do', $this_terms_tax_slug );
                set_query_var('columns',  $post_classes);
                // Get Loop template
                get_template_part('partials/loops/card', 'pair_top');

            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div><!-- end .row -->
```

And here is some code where I use a basic conditional to break the `div`s and introduce a new row...

```
    <!-- Posts row -->
    <div class="row px-2">
        <?php
            $i=0;
            // Post Loop
            while ( $posts_topic_remainder->have_posts() ) {
                $posts_topic_remainder->the_post();

                // Impose an offset, skip same number used in features above
                $i++;
                if($i<=$num_features) continue;




                if ($i == 19 OR $i == 31 OR $i == 43) { ?>
                </div><!-- break .row of .pair_tops -->

                    <div class="row showcase pt-4 pb-4">
                        <!-- CONTENT COLUMN -->
                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                            <!-- Posts row -->
                            <div class="row posts-row">


                                <?php
                                /* *********************************** */
                                /*           Features                  */
                                /* *********************************** */
                                 echo '<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4">';

                                        set_query_var('queried_object',$queried_object);

                                        set_query_var('use_byline', 'true');

                                        if ( $queried_object->slug == 'essays') {
                                             set_query_var('use_source', 'true');
                                        } else {
                                             set_query_var('use_source', 'false');
                                        }

                                        if ($queried_object->name == 'session') {
                                             $card_type = 'overlay_session';
                                        } else {
                                             $card_type = 'overlay';
                                        }
                                        get_template_part('partials/loops/card', $card_type);

                                 echo '</div>';
                                ?>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row px-2"><!-- resume .row of .pair_tops -->
                <?php
                }


                // Tell loop template which taxonomy to loop through (set above ^)
                set_query_var('columns',  $post_classes);
                // Want to hide last N items for responsive-space reasons? Pass these vars

                // Get Loop template
                get_template_part('partials/loops/card', 'pair_top');

            }
            wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </div><!-- end .row -->
```

That gets me to this, which is half-way...

[image]

The issues with my code are...

- Whilst I have successfully introduced an alternate row and displayed a single post, I need to display three. How do I do that? (It is the "Features" `div` inside `.row .posts-row` which must be rendered for three posts).
- How do I then stop the three posts in question from being rendered through `card-pair_top.php` subsequently, when the standard-layout loop resumes?

I'm open to changes of approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can break this up. I think you have the right idea though to break it inside of your current loop with **$i**, but maybe something simple that is readable could be changing this:

```
if ($i == 19 OR $i == 31 OR $i == 43) { ?>
```

Into this:

```
if(
    in_array($i, range(19, 21)) ||
    in_array($i, range(31, 33)) || 
    in_array($i, range(43, 45))
) { ?>
```

You could take it a deeper and create an array that could control the number you want to start with and an offset of that number to be flagged as a *Featured* post.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: thanks. Not sure I quite understand how to get 3 posts going. If I understand correctly, your conditional would replace my conditional. But my conditional sets up one intervening row (correct) and only one post as feature (not enough). At post 19, I would want to instigate the breaking row, then render posts 19, 20 and 21 as feature, then reinstate the normal output at 22. Not sure how to accommodate that.

Comment: Yes, the conditional I wrote will allow your post as a featured post. The conditional I wrote says, If post is 19, 20, 21, 31, 32, 33, 43, 44, or 45....then render as featured. (I hope I am understanding you correctly)

Comment: Not quite, I think. You see, whilst the "features" `div` bearing `$overlay_classes` is the post for repetition 3 x times, the nested three `div`s outside it (`.row .showcase...`, `<!-- CONTENT COLUMN -->` and `<!-- Posts row -->`) construct a _single_ row designed to hold those three things. I can't just render the `card-overlay` feature card the loop flow - those depend on being wrapped by this single row mark-up. So the code needs to insert this single row at the appropriate place (as it does), then render 3 x posts as features ( so far, I have only 1), then flip back to normal.

Comment: You could drop my logic after the `<div class="row posts-row">` and close that if() statement BEFORE you close that `<div class="row posts-row">` row?? And leave your if() statement alone. It is not the cleanest thing in the world, but it will function as I think you need.

Comment: Ultimately, I decided that inserting an intermediary row to *break* the flow and inserting three posts of alternate layout was the wrong/lazy way for me to go. So, instead, I altered some CSS rules to ensure that the "feature" card is less dependent on being in that intermediary row, so that it would display properly even if normally rendered in the same flow as the regular cards. You had assumed, as you should have done, that I was using this method, but I had been over-complicating it. Thanks for also suggesting the range idea. My code now looks like https://pastebin.com/ApZSe9Zi Thanks.

Comment: @RobertAndrews, I am glad you ultimately got there!!!!

Comment: Unsure whether to mark your answer as correct. Didn't quite answer the original question, but you had the right idea in avoiding my complexity and set me thinking. At the least, I should provide an answer. Any thoughts? Let me know if any strong feelings. Thanks again.

Comment: Leave it alone, just happy things worked out for you!!!